# Sequelize / tedious MS SQL for xml path error

Tags: sql-server, node.js, sequelize.js, tedious

Using sequelize.query, I'm executing a query that is using the STUFF() function which in turn executes a subquery that includes "for xml path('')". The purpose is to return a single string value that is a concatenation of the values returned by the subquery.

The query is tested and works perfectly in MS SQL Server Management Studio. But Sequelize returns "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'for'" It seems it or tedious attempts to parse the query and has decided it does not like it.

Anyone experience this or can suggest a solution?

Comment: Look at several options discussed here: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/

Comment: A good summary of the possible approaches, which includes the FOR XML solution I'm trying to use - and which is clearly the most concise and simple solution.

Again though, my query works fine in SQL Server itself and returns  EXACTLY the results I want. The issue is that Sequelize and/or Tedious libraries are rejecting it for some reason and I'm hoping to solve that so it can be used in my application. Thanks.

Comment: The T-SQL "for xml path"  syntax is unique to that variant of SQL. It is quite possible the library you want to use simply does not recognize or permit that syntax.

Answer (score 0):

This has been resolved.

Turns out I had a problem in my javascript that was generating the SQL. The error message led me off in the wrong direction but I finally figured it out. So as should be the case, the Sequelize/Tedious libraries are not in fact interfering with raw SQL passed to them.